# Why is it scrolling?

Tags: html

I'm not sure what is causing my webpage to have a scroll bar. 
jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XhvEx/

```
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#menu` item is 100% + 10px in height:

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:100%;
    background:#4d4d4d;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Heights **do not** include padding. Reduce the percentage height, or remove the top and bottom padding from `#menu`.

Comment: Heights CAN include padding. `box-sizing: border-box;` FYI.

Comment: I suggest changing it to `padding: 0px 5px;`

Comment: @Leeish - Not in a cross-browser way, FYI.

Comment: Nothing is completely cross-browser that is worth a darn. You'll need a javascript/alternate style sheet for everything. But yes, IE8 and older has issues.

Comment: @philipvr indeed, as I suggested 'remove the top and bottom padding'.

Comment: Not just IE8, solid support for `box-sizing` is < 19%.

Comment: Chrome, Safari, FireFox, and IE9 as far as I can tell. How is that less than 19%? Border-box is 94%.

Comment: FF is the only browser that offers **full** support for the property > http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: Yes, but my comment was on using border-box which fixes his issue which has 94% support. The 6% can deal with a scroll bar.

Comment: Well, now that we've spammed the answer with pointless discussion, let's leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

The height of 100 percent in combination with padding (which goes on the outside) seems to be what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

On #menu you have specified 100% height and 5px padding.

The complete width/height of an element is made up of it's specified width/height + padding + border + margins.

See the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) for more information.